# Load chrome extensions using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium

Is it possible to use puppeteer and load chrome extensions?
I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
    puppeteer.launch({ 
      headless: false,
      args: [
      '--load-extension="path\to\extension"' ]
      }).then(async browser => {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
    })
```

And furthermore the `"path\to\extensions"` should point to the `unpacked extensions` or to the `crx file`?
I tried both options but neither worked.

Comment: try adding `--disable-extensions-except="path/to/folder/that/manifest.json/resides"` to the args and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now. The correct syntax for the path turned out to be without the double quotes. So: `args: [ '--load-extension=path/to/folder/that/manifest.json/resides', '--disable-extensions-except=path/to/folder/that/manifest.json/resides']`